# Spring access modifiers private

Tags: java, encapsulation, access-modifiers

I am new to Spring and while learning the concepts I noticed that all the members are kept private i.e private access modifier is used.

eg.

```
private String car;
```

Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, it is a Java concept. Furthermore, it is a lot faster and easier to find the answer to this than to post this question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind private members is that the class itself retains the responsibility of its internal state, instead of the calling class. Consider a banking account class. You wouldn't want a calling class to be able to access its amount directly. Instead, you would provide other methods which contain logic, based on what the calling class wants.

```
private int amount;

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void withdraw(int amount) {
    if (this.amount - amount >= 0) {
        this.amount -= amount;
    }
}

public void deposit(int amount) {
    this.amount += amount;
}
```

The above class would allow a calling class to make deposits, withdrawals and inspect the amount, while the class itself would retain responsibility over its state.